# Changes to PHP files on LAMP server not taking effect

Tags: php

I've been working on a development LAMP server for some months with no issue.

Recently, whenever I update a file on the webserver, the changes I make are not taking affect. I've confirmed that the modified file has been uploaded to the filesystem from a shell, but none of the additions are taking effect when I run the file in a browser.

Anyone have any idea of what this could be?

EDIT:
Okay I found the issue. The file I was making an update to was a PHP include in another folder. At the top of the parent file was this line:

```
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/usr/share/xxxx/zzzz');
```

For unknown reasons, this stopped working (possibly the include_path in the ini was somehow changed).

I had to change the PHP includes to contain the full path to the includes and then my updates began to work.

Comment: Try Ctrl+F5 to refresh from server (pages are being cached by browser?) Also, please confirm that you are accessing the page via its URL on the Net and not some other way..?

Comment: I've tried that. Also tried deleting and re-uploading the file on the server, still no go.

Comment: Yes I'm accessing it from a URL in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can see cached version (try to to force refresh - CTLR-F5) Or you changing the files in the different location than they are being served from. Check your httpd config and see if both location matches.